# Java 8 in Cloud9

Tags: java, cloud9-ide

Is it possible to install JDK 8 on Cloud9? Java 7 is already installed:

```
samueller@test:~/workspace $ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_55
samueller@test:~/workspace $ java -version
java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually prefer webupd8 PPA because they keep Oracle Java as fresh as they can, so I can get the latest Oracle Java without needing take care about version number changes.

To install Webupd8 PPA, you just need to follow [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html) tutorial, and at end you can do `apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default`.

Comment: it worked! I had to click on the link for java8 in the link you gave.

Answer (score 3):

[This post](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manually-install-oracle-java-on-a-debian-or-ubuntu-vps), which I found by Googling "download jdk8 linux 64 ubuntu", answers your question. Use:

```
$ wget --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" \
  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u20-b26/jdk-8u20-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

and follow instructions to install it.

Comment: Not a very helpful first part of the first sentence, but the rest worked perfect :).

Comment: Actually, the first part of the sentence is quite helpful, as it's an excellent example of how to use Google to get quick answers to technical questions; a skill which is quite useful to the technical and non-technical alike.

Comment: Ironically though, going forward this answer will only be read by people who already use Google (as you typically land on an existing Stackoverflow question/answer via search), so the suggestion to "just google it" is now supernumerary.